# How to mock lazy initialized Bean using Junit Mockito

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have a class where I autowired it using lazy initialization in constructor. But Iam unable to mock it using @Mock. It throws null pointer exception in my test class.

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class A{
 private  B b;


  @Autowired
  public A(@Lazy B b {
      this.b= b;
  }
}  

Iam unable to mock the bean B.My test class is as follows.

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ATest{

  @Rule
  public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();



  @InjectMocks
  A a;
  @Mock
  B b;
  Mockito.when(b.methodCall()).thenReturn("test");
}
```

The above code returns null pointer exception as Iam unable to mock class B.Please let me know how to mock this.

Comment: Please add the stacktrace. Also add `class B` (and the missing test method).

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure it is not the best solution but I resolved it using reflection

```
    @Before
    public void before() {
        ReflectionUtils.setField(ReflectionUtils.findRequiredField(A.class, "b"), a, b);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using constructor injection with `@Autowired` and `@Lazy` annotation should be at the place above the method. Please try :

Class A :

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class A {

    private B b;

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Class B :

```
@Component
public class B {

    public String methodCall() {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private A a;

    @Mock
    private B b;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        Mockito.when(b.methodCall()).thenReturn("test");
    }

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        assertEquals(b.methodCall(), "test");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug with the @InjectMocks annotation code.
Building and running the application works fine for me, but @InjectMocks fails to inject the Lazy one if an Autowired field instead of a constructor parameter.

```
private final Service1 s1;

@Autowired
@Lazy
private Service2 s2;

public ParentImpl (
    Service1 s1
) {...}
```

^^ s2 is null

## Solution for Me:

If I inject the Lazy service into the constructor, though, it works fine.

```
private final Service1 s1;

private final Service2 s2;

public ParentImpl (
    Service1 s1,
    @Lazy Service2 s2
) {...}
```

^^ s2 is populated as expected